# Accessing specific value from single key-multiple value containers

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I am trying to implement a multi-value containers using C++ and to freely access each of the values inside. I have int key; values like X, Y, Width, Height as input.

I am trying to extract the values from each key.
But obviously, the code doesn't work in this case.

I would like to get some advice whether this can be done or any predefined container libraries with better flexibility in terms of accessing multiple values.

I tried independent single-key, single-value 'multimap' containers, but it consumes too much memory space and drag performance

```
multimap<int, multimap <multimap<int, int>, multimap<int, int>>> BlobPos = {};
//[<1,{(2,3),(4,5)}>,<2,{(6,7),(8,9)}>


for (auto it = BlobPos.begin();it != BlobPos.end(); it++) { 
auto X = it->second-> first->first; 
auto Y = it->second->first->second;
auto H = it->second->second->first;
auto W =  it->second-second->second;

cout << X << Y << H << W;
```

2 3 4 5
   6 7 8 9

Comment: _"But obviously, the code doesn't work in this case."_ Please clearly state the problem, including what's not happening that should, what's happening that shouldn't, what you've done to try to fix it, etc. And present your [mcve].

Comment: Why don't you group `X, Y, Width, Height` in a structure?

Comment: What exactly do you want? I'm very certain that this deep level multi-mapping isn't required.

Comment: Triply (even doubly) nested `multimap`s are a red flag.

Comment: Programming by guessing does not work. Looks like you throw random structures without any understanding how they function. You need to read a textbook first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  my real case here is working with neural network, which it will continuously feed in me the inputs(X,Y,W,H), and my code will create label based on the input. So now I've a overlapping label issue, that's why i was trying to use a container to store previous inputs to compare with current one (from the network), this is to filter out the overlapping ones...... Hope this make things clearer

Comment: @Ajay please refer my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a container structured nearly as described in your question:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::map<int, std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>>> BlobPos = {{1, {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}}, {2, {{6, 7}, {8, 9}}}};
    for (auto it = BlobPos.begin();it != BlobPos.end(); it++) { 
        auto X = it->second.first.first; 
        auto Y = it->second.first.second;
        auto H = it->second.second.first;
        auto W = it->second.second.second;

        std::cout << X << Y << H << W << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reference need the operator `->` but the next levels use operator `.` to access the elements.